# How to load images from a web and save image to isolated storage?

Tags: windows-phone-7

String url1 = "http://localhost/Images/Map.png";
I want to load images"Map.png" from this link then saving to  isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

public void GetImages()

```
    {

            WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();

            Uri m_uri = new Uri("http://localhost/Images/Map.png");

            m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

            m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(m_uri);

        }             


   void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count;

        Stream stream = e.Result;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())

```
        {

            // isf.Remove();
            //if (!isf.FileExists("map"))
            //{


            using (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("map", FileMode.Create, isf))
            {
                count = 0;

                while (0 < (count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
                {
                    isfs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                stream.Close();
                isfs.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be usefull for windows 8 phone

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411